# facebook access token timeout - how to handle this with a simple json feed on my website

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-access-token

I have a simple facebook site feed on my website, it allows no interaction by visitors to my site. It is literally a set of json dumped to a userlist.

The issue I am having is that the access token expires every 1-2 hours and the feed dies...

I need to automate the refreshing of a token or get a non expiring token. What is the best route for me to take.

I want to ensure that security is as high as possible.

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the extended token, red this : [Extended Access Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens)

This token expires in 2 months so no need to refresh this again and again.

And if you want to offline access on behalf of this user, you can use this and refresh it before its getting expired.